# Object array not persisting throughout iOS program

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I am making a application that parses JSON and creates an associated UITableView. Here is some of the code:

```
        NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&error];
        NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Call Support Desk", @"Call Genius Bar", nil];

        for (NSString *name in [jsonDict valueForKeyPath:@"name"]) {
            NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:name];
            Company *company = [[Company alloc] initWithName:tempString available_actions:tempArray];
            [self addCompany:company];
            NSLog(@"array: %@", _companyList);
```

When the NSLog prints out the Array it says there are two objects and has all the correct data that is associated with the Objects. Later when I am returning the count of objects in the array (should be 2) it says there is none:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataController countOfList];
}
```

I am new to iOS programming so any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't see that second few lines of code accessing any of the variables in the first (nor do I see it NSLogging anything).

Comment: Well, you are logging _companyList but then you are trying to get the count of another variable.

Comment: _companyList is an NSMutableArray that holds company objects. The function countOfList simply returns the number of items in _companyList

Comment: Can you check if self.dataController is nil, can you check inside the countOfList that the _companyList is not nil?

Comment: Pls show the definition of _companyList. Also, when you log the array successfully, please also log "self". Then in your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, please log 'self.dataController'

Comment: and why don't you just use `_companyList.count`

Comment: @property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *companyList;

I logged self CompanyDataController and got <CompanyDataController: 0x71dfb50>

I logged self.dataController in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection and got <CompanyDataController: 0x716d340>

Comment: Well, there is your problem. You have two different instances of CompanyDataController. Only one of them has the array you want. How did you create 'self.dataController'?

Comment: An instance of CompanyDataController is only created in the MasterViewController so I do not see how there could be two instances of it.