# dispatch_async not being called

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am having a problem storing JSON data into an Array of individual objects. It seems like the problem is in the execution of dispatch_asynch which is handling the JSON request. WHen I create a breakpoint before the method and than step through the application it seems to just fall through the block sent into dispatch_async.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sleepy-dusk-3603.herokuapp.com/companies.json"];
    NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"\nJSON: %@ \n Error: %@", json, error);

    if(!error) {
        NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&error];
        NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Call Support Desk", @"Call Genius Bar", nil];

        for (NSString *name in [jsonDict valueForKeyPath:@"name"]) {
            NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:name];
            Company *company = [[Company alloc] initWithName:tempString available_actions:tempArray];
            [self addCompany:company];
```

I truly appreciate everyone's help and support with this issue.

Comment: Did you put the breakpoint inside the block? Or the `dispatch_async` call?

Comment: When I put the breakpoint inside the block, everything seems to work fine (except my UITableView is not being fed the data for some reason). When I put the breakpoint on the original method that calls generate_default_data -> which in turn calls the dispatch_async call, things to not work.

Comment: Basically I am trying to figure out why the length of an array is 2 within the dispatch_async block, which it is suppose to be...and why it is 0 outside the block.

Comment: What array are you referring to?  Also test `if (json != nil)`, not `if (!error)`.  Also why are you using `NSASCIIStringEncoding`?  Are you sure it's not UTF-8?

Comment: Also I believe what you are experiencing with the "block falling through" is correct behaviour.  If you think about it, you have scheduled the block to be executed on a different thread to the current thread and so the debugger won't step through it (it won't change to a different thread unless you tell it to).

Comment: @trojanfoe  :its a working code.I tested it

Comment: What array is 0? IS it possible your checking the count of the array before the block has returned?

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far! I think the kind folks of StackOverflow have helped me identify the fact that the array is being counted as 0 before dispatch_async returns. I'm looking into an alternative now..

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(!error) {
...
      }
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Log the error and find what is happening

this code i tried and is working very well

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sleepy-dusk-3603.herokuapp.com/companies.json"];
    NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"\nJSON: %@ \n Error: %@", json, error);

    if(!error) {
        NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&error];
        NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Call Support Desk", @"Call Genius Bar", nil];

        for (NSString *name in [jsonDict valueForKeyPath:@"name"]) {
            NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:name];
            NSLog(@"%@",tempString);
        }
    }
});
```

Response

```
2013-03-05 22:02:44.312 newTrial[4711:12303] 
JSON: [{"created_at":"2013-03-04T00:09:06Z","id":1,"name":"Apple","updated_at":"2013-03-04T00:09:06Z","actions":[{"created_at":"2013-03-04T00:09:07Z","id":1,"name":"Call Support Desk","updated_at":"2013-03-04T00:09:07Z"},{"created_at":"2013-03-04T00:09:07Z","id":2,"name":"Call Genius Bar","updated_at":"2013-03-04T00:09:07Z"}]},{"created_at":"2013-03-04T02:01:49Z","id":2,"name":"Comcast","updated_at":"2013-03-04T02:01:49Z","actions":[{"created_at":"2013-03-04T02:01:49Z","id":3,"name":"Account Services","updated_at":"2013-03-04T02:01:49Z"}]}] 
 Error: (null)
2013-03-05 22:02:51.766 newTrial[4711:12303] Apple
```

So my assumption of the problem is at where you store the value to the array .Check it is properly initialised
problem may be here

```
Company *company = [[Company alloc] initWithName:tempString available_actions:tempArray];
[self addCompany:company];
```

Comment: It seems to never even execute the (!error) block either since it skips over the entire block sent to dispatch_queue

Comment: Julian25 - I think you're misunderstanding the way GCD works in the debugger. If you step over or into the dispatch_async call it won't call the block immediately. The block won't be called until you continue

Comment: That is actually quite helpful. I guess I did misunderstand how the GCD worked in the debugger. In regards to other answers provided...the root problem I am having is discussed here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214830/object-array-not-persisting-throughout-ios-program#comment21445661_15214830

Answer (score 0):

it works for me like a charm:

```
dispatch_queue_t _queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
    NSError *_error = nil;
    NSURL *_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sleepy-dusk-3603.herokuapp.com/companies.json"];
    NSData *_json = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url];
    if (_json) {
         id _response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_json options:kNilOptions error:&_error];
         if (!_error) {
            // do whatever you want to do here...
         } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", _response);
         }
    }
});
```

---

the response is:

```
(
        {
        actions =         (
                        {
                "created_at" = "2013-03-04T00:09:07Z";
                id = 1;
                name = "Call Support Desk";
                "updated_at" = "2013-03-04T00:09:07Z";
            },
                        {
                "created_at" = "2013-03-04T00:09:07Z";
                id = 2;
                name = "Call Genius Bar";
                "updated_at" = "2013-03-04T00:09:07Z";
            }
        );
        "created_at" = "2013-03-04T00:09:06Z";
        id = 1;
        name = Apple;
        "updated_at" = "2013-03-04T00:09:06Z";
    },
        {
        actions =         (
                        {
                "created_at" = "2013-03-04T02:01:49Z";
                id = 3;
                name = "Account Services";
                "updated_at" = "2013-03-04T02:01:49Z";
            }
        );
        "created_at" = "2013-03-04T02:01:49Z";
        id = 2;
        name = Comcast;
        "updated_at" = "2013-03-04T02:01:49Z";
    }
)
```